# Удаление нескольких элементов из динамического массива

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist, динамические-массивы

Есть два массива, один динамический:

```java
ArrayList<String[]> myPoints;
```

и другой обычный:

```java
int[] arr_select_item;
```

Изначально они равны по размеру:

```java
arr_select_item = new int[myPoints.size()];
```

В обычном массиве элементы равны либо 0, либо 1.

Надо пробежаться циклом по обычному массиву, и из динамического массива удалить элементы, которые в обычном массиве = 1.
Но дело в том, что динамический массив меняет размер после удаления, и уже начинается путаница.

Что-то типа этого (не правильный код):

```java
for (int i = 0; i < arr_select_item.length; i++) {
    if (arr_select_item[i] == 1) {
        myPoints.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Подскажите пример.

Comment: Удаляйте с конца к началу

Comment: И вообще, почему бы логику `arr_select_item` и `myPoints` не соединить в какой-то `HashMap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рабочий пример

```
    Iterator<String> iterator = myPoints.iterator();
    int count = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
        if (arr[count] == 1) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
        count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну так это его правильное поведение. Элементы, следующие после удалённого элемента, сдвигаются влево, а размер списочного массива уменьшается на единицу.

Вы либо удаляйте с конца, либо при **каждом** удалении у индекса отнимайте единицу, так как все элементы смещаются влево (т.е индекс изменяется на -1)

Comment: Если я после myPoints.remove(i); добавлю i--, то возникает ошибка

Comment: Я имел ввиду myPoints.remove(i-1); i-2; i-3. Но для этого нужно завести переменную для сохранение количества удаления. Это костыли, лучше смотрите другое решение

Comment: Спасибо, вот так вроде работает for (int i = arr_select_item.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {...

Answer (score 0):

Можно новый лист собрать из выбранных элементов:

```java
List<String> points =
        Arrays.asList("point1", "point2", "point3", "point4", "point5");

int[] selected = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1};

List<String> selectedPoints = IntStream
        // обходим индексы массива 'int[]'
        .range(0, selected.length)
        // отбираем индексы равные 1
        .filter(i -> selected[i] == 1)
        // получаем элементы 'List<String>'
        // по индексам из массива 'int[]'
        .mapToObj(i -> points.get(i))
        // собираем в лист
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(selectedPoints); // [point1, point3, point5]
```